# Finding the next occurrence of something using InStr on the same string input

Tags: excel, vba, string

I currently am reading data of an address in a csv file separated by commas. The data looks like this :

```
123 Main St, Rubber Boots, MANITOBA
```

The order of the data is always street address, city, province.

I am trying to use InStr to find the location of the comma, which I can do for the first one easily, but using it to find the 2nd occurrence is an issue. I am trying to take each substring and trim it to output into its own cell in excel. When trimming the mid substring I am still left over with the rest of the string, is there a way around this so that "MANITOBA" will be in its own cell? Thanks!

```
city = ""
province = ""
streetAddress = ""
shippingAddress = CStr(Sheet1.Cells(currRawRow, "C"))
commaPos = InStr(1, shippingAddress, ",")
If (commaPos > 0) Then
     streetAddress = Trim(Left(shippingAddress, (commaPos - 1)))
     commaPos = InStr(commaPos, shippingAddress, ",")
     city = Trim(Mid(shippingAddress, (commaPos + 1)))
End If
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**
[image]

**UPDATED CODE USING SPLIT:**

```
city = ""
province = ""
streetAddress = ""
shippingAddress = CStr(Sheet1.Cells(currRawRow, "C"))
shippingParts = Split(shippingAddress, ",")
streetAddress = shippingParts(0)
city = shippingParts(1)
province = shippingParts(2)
```

**UPDATED OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: If the elements are consistently comma-separated, consider using `Split` instead, to break the string into an array of `n+1` elements, where `n` is the number of commas in the string. Then you can `Trim` individual elements as needed. Won't work if one of the strings has a legit comma, but then an `InStr` approach would break all the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Split` instead of `Instr` if possible.

```
Sub tester()
    Dim s As String
    Dim a() As String

    s = "123 Main St, Rubber Boots, MANITOBA"

    a = Split(s, ",")

    Debug.Print a(0)
    Debug.Print a(1)
    Debug.Print a(2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I dont know why my prof would hint at using InStr multiple times if this worked flawlessly without turning my brain to oatmeal. Thank you!

Comment: @RocktheFries If it's for class, are you sure the professor isn't specifically introducing a more difficult version for the sake of the lesson?

Comment: We can use any function present in VBA specifically, he just hinted in the comments that you might want to figure out how to call InStr() multiple times, but with the hours I've speant trying to get it to work, theres issues all over the place when its more than 2 things seperated by commas.

Comment: It seems VBA has issues when trying to reference the last spot InStr() found the comma and using that as a new index, at this point im very happy with Split() and just about had it with InStr()'s nonsense.

Comment: @RocktheFries Definitely, split makes more sense in this context. For the sake of completeness, using `Instr`, you'd get the index of the first comma, and and then pass that + 1 as the first argument to a subsequent call to Instr. For example: `a = Instr(s, ",")`, then `b = Instr(a + 1, s, ",")`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub manitoba()
Const addressString = "123 Main St, Rubber Boots, MANITOBA"
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim str3 As String
Dim tempString As String
tempString = addressString

str1 = Mid(tempString, 1, InStr(tempString, ",") - 1)
tempString = Mid(tempString, InStr(tempString, ",") + 1, Len(tempString))
Debug.Print str1

str2 = Mid(tempString, 1, InStr(tempString, ",") - 1)
Debug.Print str2

str3 = Mid(tempString, InStr(tempString, ",") + 1, Len(tempString))
Debug.Print str3
End Sub
```

I am sure someone can even work out a more elegant recursive function. I am currently too tired for that :P